# JavaScript Object with children need to convert into SQL like Array (nosql data format to sql)

Tags: javascript, nosql

I have array of data and some of the properties are arrays. I wan to flatten that array so none of the properties are array as explained below.

**Input**

```
[{
    "name": "James",
    "education": [
        { "year": 2014, "degree": "MS" },
        { "year": 2012, "degree": "BS" }]
}, {
    "name": "Bond",
    "education": [
        { "year": 2011, "degree": "MS" },
        { "year": 2009, "degree": "BS" }]
}]
```

**Output**

```
[
    {"name":"James","education_year":2014,"education_degree":"MS"},
    {"name":"James","education_year":2012,"education_degree":"BS"},
    {"name":"Bond","education_year":2011,"education_degree":"MS"},
    {"name":"Bond","education_year":2009,"education_degree":"BS"}
]
```

https://sqlify.io/convert does that when i ask it to convert to CSV format. But i cant use that service.

Is there any way so i can produce desired output,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate with [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and then map `education` to new objects in the requested format. Flatten the results using [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

create the object with Object#assign. Inside the assign, Array#map each property to the required format, and spread:

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "James",
    "education": [
        { "year": 2014, "degree": "MS" },
        { "year": 2012, "degree": "BS" }]
}, {
    "name": "Bond",
    "education": [
        { "year": 2011, "degree": "MS" },
        { "year": 2009, "degree": "BS" }]
}];

const result = [].concat(...data.map(({ name, education }) => 
  education.map(({ year, degree }) => ({ name, education_year: year, education_degree: degree })
)));

console.log(result);
```

A generic version that can handle multiple sub arrays in objects:

```js
const data = [{"name":"James","lname":"Parker","education":[{"year":2014,"degree":"MS"},{"year":2012,"degree":"BS"}],"job":[{"year":2017,"title":"senior developer"},{"year":2017,"title":"developer"},{"year":2014,"title":"junior"}]},{"name":"Bond","lname":"Peter","education":[{"year":2011,"degree":"MS"},{"year":2009,"degree":"BS"}],"job":[{"year":2014,"title":"ninja"},{"year":2012,"title":"rogue"}]}];

const createKey = (prefix, key) => `${prefix}_${key}`;

const result = [].concat(...data.map((el) => 
 Object.entries(el)
    .map(([k, v]) => Array.isArray(v) ? 
      v.map((o) => Object.entries(o).reduce((r, [key, val]) => Object.assign(r, { [createKey(k, key)]: val }), {}))
      :
      { [k]: v }
    )
   .reduce((r, s) =>
     Array.isArray(s) ?
       [].concat(...r.map((o) => s.map((q) => Object.assign({}, o, q))))
        :
        r.map((o) => Object.assign({}, o, s))
      , [{}])
));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you accepting this answer but my problem is i have huge number of properties so anything hard coded won't work. like property "name", education degree etc. but this is a good starting point i can take from here and create some generic function. will post once i finish.

Comment: Updated with a generic version that can handle multiple sub arrays in an object.